# VBA: Match results regardless of the indexes sorting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 worksheets (user1, user2, result). Each sheet has three columns (A: System_ID, B: Comment, C: Last Modified Time).

The code does this:

1. Gets maximum last modified time between user1 and user2 in column c.
2. The result is to get that comment in column b (adjacent to max time found in col c)
3. put the result (comment) in column b in resut sheet

Simply the comment with last modified time wins and gets pasted in result WS.

Anyways, my problem is that I only can index-match if both indexes in column A have the same sorting/order.

I need to match all records in column A even if they have different row.number or row index.

**How to index-match no matter the order in column A**

```
        Sub Get_LastModified_Here()
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim Location1 As Workbook
        Set Location1 = GetWorkbook("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\User_1.xlsb")
        Dim Location2 As Workbook
        Set Location2 = GetWorkbook("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\User_2.xlsb")
        
        Dim SourceCell As Range, SourceRange As Range, CurrentRange As Range
        Dim rngTarget As Range
        Dim strAdr As String
        Dim vSource As Variant, vTarget As Variant, vCurrent As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        
        Set SourceRange = Workbooks("User_2.xlsb").Sheets("Data").Range("A2:" & "A1607")
        
        With SourceRange
            Set SourceRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + 3)
        End With
        
        strAdr = SourceRange.Address
        
        Set rngTarget = Workbooks("User_1.xlsb").Worksheets("Data").Range(strAdr)
        
        Set CurrentRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(strAdr).Offset(0, 1)
        
        vSource = SourceRange
        vTarget = rngTarget
        vCurrent = CurrentRange
        
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(vSource, 1)
             'Match Column A
             If vSource(i, 1) = vTarget(i, 1) Then
                'Check max time in Column C (user1 vs user2)
                 If vSource(i, 3) > vTarget(i, 3) Then
                    'Get max comment from ((user max)) in column B  (result ws)
                    vCurrent(i, 1) = vSource(i, 2)
                    
                ElseIf vSource(i, 3) < vTarget(i, 3) Then
                    vCurrent(i, 1) = vTarget(i, 2)
                ElseIf vSource(i, 3) = vTarget(i, 3) Then
                    vCurrent(i, 1) = vSource(i, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        SourceRange = vSource
        rngTarget = vTarget
        CurrentRange = vCurrent
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End Sub
```

Here is a detailed explanation of the issue (I apologize for CAPS letters):

**User1 Sheet**

I have the **SYSTEM_ID** in ## **Row 1** ##

| System_ID | Comment | LastModTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | User1 notes | 09/12/2020 10:00:01 PM |

**User2 Sheet**

I have the **SAME SYSTEM_ID** in ## **Row 2**  ##

| System_ID | Comment | LastModTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| ID_1 | User2 notes | 09/12/2020 10:00:02 PM |

**This is what I GET in Result Sheet**

I have the **SAME SYSTEM_ID** but in ## **Row 3** ##

| System_ID | Comment | LastModTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| ID_1 |  |  |

**This is what I Want in Result Sheet**

I have the **SAME SYSTEM_ID** but in ## **Row 3** ##

| System_ID | Comment | LastModTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| ID_1 | User2 notes | 09/12/2020 10:00:02 PM |

**What our codes CAN do**

Get the comment based on the last modified time, **ONLY IF "ID_1" is on THE SAME ROW #.** i have tried it (didn't work)

**What our codes CAN'T do**

Get the comment based on the last modified time, **EVEN IF "ID_1" is on A DIFFERENT ROW #.** this is where I need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT to confirm that the assumptions match:

Sheet User1:
| Id  | Comment | LastMod |
| --- | ------- | --------|
| 3   | S1 Comm3| 2       |
| 2   | S1 Comm2| 8       |
| 1   | S1 Comm1| 6       |

Sheet User2:
| Id  | Comment | LastMod |
| --- | ------- | --------|
| 1   | S2 Comm1| 3       |
| 2   | S2 Comm2| 4       |
| 3   | S2 Comm3| 8       |

Expected Output:

| Id | Comment | NOTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 Comm1 | Id 1 highest mod is on sheet 1 |
| 2 | S1 Comm2 | Id 2 highest mod is on sheet 2 |
| 3 | S2 Comm3 | Id 3 highest mod is on sheet 3 |

One option is to build up the result set into a separate collection, and then populate your result set when finished. Since this is an operation that involved multiple lookups (checking to see if a system Id has already been visited), I like to use dictionary objects. These offer highly performant lookup operations.

I'm going to post a much simplified example below that you can hopefully use for your purposes. The code below assumes that the SystemId column is a unique key that maps an entry in sheet1 to an entry in sheet2. It also assumes that each systemId appears once per sheet. If not, it can be tweaked to support that.

The code basically loops through the range and checks if the rows in both sheets have matching system ID. If so, it adds that row to the dictionary, using the ID as a key, and a two element array containing the comment and the last mod time.

If they don't match, it checks each entry against the dictionary to see if that systemID was already visited (earlier on the other sheet). If so, it compares the entries and keeps the most recent mod time, otherwise, it leaves it as is.

Try to work through it and let us know if you need additional help.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim a(0 To 1)
    Dim sUser1 As Worksheet
    Dim sUser2 As Worksheet
    
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set sUser1 = Sheets("User1")
    Set sUser2 = Sheets("User2")
    
    'Here I will assume that both ranges will always
    'be the same length. I'm also hardcoding in the
    'needed rows. You can use whichever logic
    'works best for you to determine how to capture
    'all rows in both sheets
    For i = 2 To 8
        'Two possibilities here:
        '   1. The SystemId in both sheets match and
        '      can be directly compared
        '   2. They differ and will each be checked
        '      to see if they already exist in the dict.
        'You can bypass this and just treat each of the
        'ranges individually, but I think it would be
        'slightly more performant the way I'm doing it.
        '
        'Also, this assumes that each SystemId will only
        'appear once in each sheet, and is a true Primary Key
        If sUser1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sUser2.Cells(i, 1) Then
            If sUser1.Cells(i, 3).Value > sUser2.Cells(i, 3).Value Then
                MergeEntryToDictionary oDict, sUser1.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                    sUser1.Cells(i, 2).Value, sUser1.Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else
                MergeEntryToDictionary oDict, sUser2.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                    sUser2.Cells(i, 2).Value, sUser2.Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
        Else
            'In case they don't match, check each entry against the
            'dictionary to see if the systemId has already been added.
            'If not, then add it. Otherwise, compare the last mod date
            'of the entry to the current, and update if needed.
            MergeEntryToDictionary oDict, sUser1.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                    sUser1.Cells(i, 2).Value, sUser1.Cells(i, 3).Value
            
            MergeEntryToDictionary oDict, sUser2.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                    sUser2.Cells(i, 2).Value, sUser2.Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Below prints back to sheet
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    n = 2
    For Each k In oDict.keys
        Sheets("result").Cells(n, 1).Value = k
        Sheets("result").Cells(n, 2).Value = oDict(k)(0)
        Sheets("result").Cells(n, 3).Value = oDict(k)(1)
        
        n = n + 1
    Next k
End Sub

Function MergeEntryToDictionary(ByRef oDict As Object, _
                                SystemId As String, _
                                sComment As String, _
                                LastModTime As Double) As Boolean
    Dim a(0 To 2)
    
    If oDict.exists(SystemId) Then
        If LastModTime > oDict(SystemId)(1) Then
            a(0) = sComment
            a(1) = LastModTime
            oDict(SystemId) = a
        End If
    Else
        a(0) = sComment
        a(1) = LastModTime
        
        oDict.Add SystemId, a
    End If
    
    MergeEntryToDictionary = True
End Function
```

Comment: From all my heart I sincerely thank you very much for your help! I just need a little modification here if you please, I tried to make different sorting in all sheets, in user1 sheet range("a2") = ID_1, in user2 sheet range("a3") = ID_1, in result("range("a4") = ID_1. I need to match IDs based on their common (value = ID_1) not based on their address ("a2").offset(0,2). thanks :D

Comment: it works perfect if all primary keys have the same (order/sort) I just need to match them even if they are ordered differently  "match results regardless of the indexes sorting?"

Comment: @zatary the code I wrote doesn’t discriminate based on location. The offset function is used to fetch the values from columns B and C (comment and time stamp). The code works whether or not the IDs have the same matching row number. Does that not work for you?

Comment: I am sorry unfortunately it didn't, it does exactly as my code in the question. If you give it a try at your pc it won't work as needed. try to put the three columns in three sheets but in column A put ("ID_1") in different places like in sht user1 in row 2, in sh user2 row 3 and so on, you will find that comments will not reflect unless all three have the same row number  only then it works, but if the same system_id is in different row numbers it won't work

Comment: @Zatary I made an edit to my answer. At the top of the post, I input three tables showing the values in sheets user1, and user2. Then I show my expected output, which matches the output my code generates. Does this match your expected inputs and outputs? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question in tables to illustrate my issue just below the code, thanks for your patience :) I couldn't edit the answer, please check my edited question - Simply put the difference is that I am asking about matching( the same unique system_id) in all sheets in different row # in column A [system_id doesn't necessarily have to have the same row# in all sheets to reflect the latest user comments]

Comment: Hi, any ideas regarding this question? thanks

Comment: @Zatary I edited the code to also copy the last mod time to the results sheet. I also modified the function to accept a datetime for the timestamp. Otherwise, the code works for me. I'm not sure why it's throwing issues on your workbook. I reproduced a workbook, put the IDs in separate rows, and it took only the newest timestamp in each case.